# Simple Javascript not Working - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following in my page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function setTheTimeout(){
        var t=setTimeout("alertMsg()",3000);
    }
    function alertMsg(){
        alert("Hello");
    }
    setTheTimeout();
});
```

I am getting an error in Firebug alertMsg() is not defined?

Comment: You don't need to assign "t" if you're never going to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
var t=setTimeout("alertMsg()",3000);
```

To

```
var t=setTimeout(alertMsg,3000);
```

See the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#Syntax) documentation from Mozilla Developer Network.  Using a string is the same as using eval, and [eval is bad!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval!)

Comment: Why can `setTheTimeout` access `alertMsg` when passed by reference, but not when passed via an eval'd string ?

Comment: @idiqual It can't, it is a scoping issue as bfavaretto said (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9167330/219743).  I just would not recommend using a string as a parameter for the same reasons I wouldn't recommend eval.

Comment: because you're executing the reference, and eval is always bad... just pretend it doesn't exist is the best way around it!

Answer (score 2):

That function only exists in the scope of the document.ready callback. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function setTheTimeout(){
        var t=setTimeout("alertMsg()",3000);
    }

    setTheTimeout();
});

function alertMsg(){
    alert("Hello");
}
```

Comment: Scope isn't the issue in that case, your answer won't fix his problem.

Comment: @Relic, I believe scope *is* the issue here. My answer does work, and is very close to his original code. Now, that doesn't mean that I'm advocating for `eval`. I'm just not sure if this is the right place for discussing that.

Comment: @Relic, it works, your fiddle fails because it's setup to run onDomReady. See [this fork](http://jsfiddle.net/NHjkr/1/). And, in case it's not clear yet, I agree that passing the function by reference to `setTimeout` is by far the best option, eval is evil, everything. I just like it when the answers here explain what is going on, and I was trying to explain the scope problem. The implied `eval` on `setTimeout` was a secondary problem (not what was causing the reported error). Unfortunately, none of the answers here explained both issues satisfactorily (mine included).

Comment: @bfavaretto +1 well said... however, everything should be 'useable' by DOM ready just as a matter of practice, and if you're execution order is stable this will never be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take the quotes and parenthesis off the call to alertMsg (**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EbAFe/)**).

```
function setTheTimeout(){
    var t=setTimeout(alertMsg,3000);
}
function alertMsg(){
    alert("Hello");
}
setTheTimeout();
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example: http://jsbin.com/imovuk/edit#javascript,html

Use the following approach.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    function setTheTimeout(){ 
        var t=setTimeout(function () {alertMsg();},3000); 
    } 
    function alertMsg(){ 
        alert("Hello"); 
    } 
    setTheTimeout(); 
});
```

Eval is evil

Answer (score 0):

It's defined a little differently than you'd expect... try this, and call back:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function setTheTimeout(){
        var t=setTimeout(alertMsg,3000);
    }
    function alertMsg(){
        alert("Hello");
    }
    setTheTimeout();
});
```